# Can ZFC define the busy beaver function?

Tags: number-theory, set-theory

Can ZFC define the busy beaver(BB) function? That is to say, is there a formula $A(x,y)$ in the language of ZFC such that $A(x,y)$ holds precisely when $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers and $y=BB(x)$?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? How do you think we can define it at all, if we wouldn't?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am asking because the Busy Beaver function is not computable. Also, it can't be defined in Peano Arithmetic, so maybe it can't be defined in ZFC either.

Comment: How would *we* reason about it, in general? Also, since ZFC proves that there is a continuum size set of *total* functions from $\Bbb N$ to itself, and it can even define many of them (e.g. the truth predicate of $\Bbb N$), it can surely reason non-arithmetic functions.

Comment: @user107952 It **can** be defined in Peano arithmetic. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) (the graph of the Busy Beaver function is $\Pi^0_1$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the comments, this question appears based on a misconception: the Busy Beaver function is in fact already definable in the language of arithmetic, and basic facts about it (although not more than a few of its specific values) can be proved in $\mathsf{PA}$. The relevant tool here is [Post's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem), which gives us bounds on how complicated a set/function is to define in the language of arithmetic based purely on its computability-theoretic complexity - and in particular lets us show that the Busy Beaver function is definable in the language of arithmetic, since it has Turing degree ${\bf 0'}$. The expressive power of arithmetic is really quite vast.

The discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816668/there-is-any-arithmetical-set-which-is-not-recursively-enumerable/3816686#comment7869846_3816686) may be helpful.